# How to call DynamicObject.TryGetMember directly?

Tags: .net, dynamic

I'm implementing a general purpose function to extract a value from an arbitrary provided dynamic object, but don't know how to call `TryGetMember` because it requires a `GetMemberBinder` which is abstract, hence I cannot create it.
Sample...

```
public object GetValue(DynamicObject Source, string FieldName)
{
    object Result = null;
    GetMemberBinder Binder = x;  // What object must be provided?
    Binder.Name = FieldName;
    if (Source.TryGetMember(Binder, out Result))
       return Result;

    throw new Exception("The field '" + FieldName + "' not exists");
}
```

Is there an already existent concrete descendant of GetMemberBinder ready for use? or a guideline to create my own implementation?

Comment: I must be missing something... isn't this entire method exactly what the dynamic assignment operator already does, except less reliable?

Comment: My question is about getting a field value of a dynamic object while not knowing at comiple time how that field is named. So, I cannot code, for example, "var MyValue = TheDynamicObject.TheField;" because only at runtime the field name is obtained. I'm writing a general purpose class to deal with externally provided dynamic objects.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any method in the framework that actually returns a `GetMemberBinder`, but it doesn't matter - that isn't the correct way to invoke a dynamic member by name.

What you actually need to do is create a call site.  The method looks like this:

```
static object GetDynamicMember(object obj, string memberName)
{
    var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, memberName, obj.GetType(),
        new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
    var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);
    return callsite.Target(callsite, obj);
}
```

Note that `Binder.GetMember` creates a `CallSiteBinder`, **not** a `GetMemberBinder`. Just to be 100% clear.  This method will throw a `RuntimeBinderException` if the internal call to `TryGetMember` fails, so you do not need to check the result. If you don't want callers to see the `RuntimeBinderException` then wrap it in your own try/catch.

Dynamic dispatch is complex, at least relative to reflection on static types. Since the CLR is not actually dynamically typed, C# has to actually instantiate a *compiler* to figure out how to execute the member/method. That's creating a call site. As far as I know, you *have* to do this, which is why every `Binder` method returns a `CallSiteBinder` and you can't instantiate any of the binders directly.

Note that the DLR does some sort of call site caching, but I'm not sure if the automatic caching covers this scenario. There's a good chance you'll want to save your call site for future calls to avoid the overhead of constant recompilation.

P.S. If you are using (or can use) `ExpandoObject` instead of `DynamicObject` then keep in mind that it implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you don't need to do any of this. Just cast it to the dictionary type and check if the property exists.  I would only ever use `DynamicObject` over `ExpandoObject` if I were doing something a lot more complicated than simply adding members at runtime, i.e. changing the actual behaviour based on the runtime binder.

Comment: The automatic caching is stored in the callsite and also the callsitebinder so if you don't keep at least one of them you will get pretty bad performance (i've tested). That's one of the things [impromptuinterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) does for you, it will reuse the callsite it creates whenever it can.

Comment: You obviously know a lot about this subject, but if you keep posting that link you're going to [start getting spam flags](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion). At the very least it would ruffle fewer feathers if it wasn't always a hyperlink.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind but it is an open source framework that is designed to solve this specific problem which in the general case is not trivial. This case maybe trivial as get members can always have the same callsite func signature so all you need is a dictionary of callsites indexed by membername to fix this cache issue.

Comment: Good alternative. I was able to obtain the value, cache the callsite and enclose the operation in a try-catch for non-existent members. Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing an exception even when the call succeeds.

Comment: Same here, the `callSite.Target` method throws (and presumably catches) a `RuntimeBinderException` two times according to the Output window then returns the correct value.  I wonder if internally there's some nasty try ... catch logic for getting dynamic members.

Comment: Note that `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder` has `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` so don't be surprised if you don't see it in VS.

Answer (score 16):

You don't call TryGetMember directly, what you need is to use the dynamic api's directly to get the same effect by using a csharp member binder and a call site.

This is made even easier by open source framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) (via nuget) as it has a static method that does this. It works for any IDynamicMetaObjectProvider not just DynamicObject and (it works for regular types faster than reflection too).

```
return Dynamic.InvokeGet(Source, FieldName);
```

Comment: I don't get why this answer was voted down. It does exactly this now doesn't it?

Comment: @jbtule, about your user picture... Nice! Best profile?

Comment: I guess because it requires an external library @TimBourguignon

Answer (score 2):

While Aaronaught's answer explains what might be the "right" way to do something manually that I believe Dynamity already does for you, it does not actually answer the poster's question.

The question asks how to call TryGetMember( ) directly, and others should not pass judgement on the propriety of the original poster's interest in doing so.

To actually answer the question, there is only one abstract member, not counting the constructor.  In my application, the following concrete class is sufficient, and I believe the most efficient solution:

```
public class GetMemberBinder : System.Dynamic.GetMemberBinder
{
    public GetMemberBinder( [NotNull] string name, bool ignoreCase ) : base( name, ignoreCase )
    {
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject FallbackGetMember( DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion )
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException( );
    }
}
```

Microsoft has very limited documentation on the FallbackGetMember( ) method that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.getmemberbinder.fallbackgetmember?view=netstandard-2.0#system-dynamic-getmemberbinder-fallbackgetmember(system-dynamic-dynamicmetaobject-system-dynamic-dynamicmetaobject)).  It appears to me that if you either know that the dynamic object in question will successfully provide a result, or you can wrap your attempt in a try/catch block in order to handle cases where it does not, then the FallbackGetMember( ) need not be implemented.  If, however, you require full dynamic dispatch support, then Aaronaught's answer and Dynamity might be the more advisable solution--that simply is not what the question asks though.

In my case, I have a dynamic object that never fails to produce a successful result when TryGetMember( ) is called, so the overhead of true dynamic dispatch seems unreasonably expensive.

Comment: `FallbackGetMember` is there so that the language can specify its own fallback rules if the member is not there, for example returning a special value equivalent to "missing" or "null". I think it's safe to return `errorSuggestion`.