# Is it possible to serialize or save viewbag state?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

We have a custom cache system in our MVC project where we save and load our model in controllers. We utilize the Viewbag object also, but we're having trouble finding a way to save the state of this object. It's also not marked as [Serializable] so a byte-array is no-go.

Can you save the state of the Viewbag object in some way to a manageable database object?
Can you override or extend the behaviour of the Viewbag in some way?

I feel like scrapping Viewbag entirely.

Comment: Could you serialize it using something like JSON.NET?

Comment: I have not looked into JSON.NET at all. Could you give a pointer to how this would be possible?

Comment: Yes, scrap the `ViewBag` entirely or reserve it for trivial cases where it is easy to repopulate with each execution of the action method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ViewBag is a [DynamicViewDataDictionary](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DynamicViewDataDictionary.cs), which inherits [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).  Getting the keys is straightforward using "GetDynamicMemberNames", but getting the values is slightly more verbose.  The following converts the ViewBag to a dictionary (shamelessly <s>plagiarized</s> borrowed from [Aaronaught's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108263/1001985)):

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
IEnumerable<string> keys = ViewBag.GetDynamicMemberNames();
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    var binder = Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.GetMember(
        CSharpBinderFlags.None, key, 
        ViewBag.GetType(),
        new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
    var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);
    var val = callsite.Target(callsite, ViewBag);
    values.Add(key, val);
}
```

---

> I feel like scrapping Viewbag entirely.

This sounds like a good idea -- far better to use strongly-typed view models, where possible.