# Access TryGetMember from C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, c++-cli

In my C++/CLI project I try to access the `TryGetMember` method located in a class deriving from `DynamicObject`. This class is part of a C# DLL. `TryGetMember` takes a `GetMemberBinding` object as first parameter. What value should I pass?

Some people [suggest using Impromptu](http://worldhousefinder.com/?p=168683). However, I currently don't understand how Impromptu helps answering my question.

Comment: Sounds like you should not be using `TryGetMember` directly - [How to call DynamicObject.TryGetMember directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306018/how-to-call-dynamicobject-trygetmember-directly)

Comment: But that doesn't apply to C++/CLI, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in  [How to call DynamicObject.TryGetMember directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306018/how-to-call-dynamicobject-trygetmember-directly), `TryGetMember` should not be called directly. A `CallSite` has to be created instead. This also works in C++/CLI. I could get it to work using the following code:

```
Object^ dynamicObject(Object^ object, String^ memberName)
{
    array<CSharpArgumentInfo^>^ infos = { CSharpArgumentInfo::Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags::None, nullptr) };
    CallSiteBinder^ binder = RuntimeBinder::Binder::GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags::None, memberName, object->GetType(), infos);
    auto callsite = CompilerServices::CallSite<Func<CallSite^, Object^, Object^>^>::Create(binder);
    return callsite->Target(callsite, object);
}
```