# C# Dynamic object has property with at symbol

Tags: c#

I have an object from my elasticsearch resultset;
that I'm iterating true this via this foreach:

```
foreach (Nest.IHit<dynamic> temp in result.Hits) {

}
```

one `temp` it's source looks like this (just rightclicked in visual studio and clicked on "copy value")

```
{{
  "charSet": "UTF-8",
  "executionTime": 927,
  "parentUrl": "http://wfintranetdvlp.sidmar.be/sdg/",
  "@timestamp": "2015-08-05T13:50:40.721Z",
  "method": "GET",
  "contentLength": 31575,
  "mimeType": "text/html",
  "text": "You are here: Home Productie Productie Productie Sidgal Sidgal 1 Campagneplan Dagverslag PamBrowser Sidgal 2 Campagneplan Dagverslag PamBrowser Sidgal 3 Campagneplan Dagverslag PamBrowser Alle Lijnen Stilstanden Productierapporten Autonoom Onderhoud JAP AO-zones Uitgevoerde AO-activiteit afgelopen jaar Kalender audits AO",
  "title": "Productie",
  "url": "http://wfintranetdvlp.sidmar.be/sdg/productie-2/",
  "httpStatusCode": 200
}}
```

now in my code I can access the params like following `temp.Source.title` or `temp.Source.url` but when I want to access the `@timestamp` it returns `null`

any idea on how I can access the timestamp?

Comment: I thought this was a json

Comment: please add the code showing how you access these properties

Comment: It isn't json and @MichalDymel just added that :)

Answer (score 4):

C# identifiers can not start with `@`. You're actually trying to access `timestamp` - the `@` is called the verbatim specifier, and it allows you to use keywords as identifiers, e.g. you can have a local named `@this`, which is actually the `this` identifier.

The only way would be to access the variable by name, something like `yourvar["@timestamp"]`.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my original answer as I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7108263/1439998) after trying something in my code for you.

The relevant code from the answer is this:

```
static object GetDynamicMember(object obj, string memberName)
{
    var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, memberName, obj.GetType(),
    new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });
    var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);
    return callsite.Target(callsite, obj);
}
```

It uses reflection to build up the call to get the value back, and the "@timestamp" can easily be passed in as a string.